# WinForms ListView Group, customise colour and font size?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

It seems that the group's font size does not follow the font size of the ListView. How can I change the font size and the colour?
[image]

```
        MyListView.BeginUpdate();
        MyListView.Items.Clear();
        var lg = new ListViewGroup("Group Test");
        lg.Subtitle = "Does this work?";
        MyListView.Groups.Add(lg);
```

Comment: Request for custom drawing are notified, so you nee to read the type of [NMHDR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-nmhdr) referenced in lParam, check whether it's of the generic [NM_CUSTOMDRAW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw) type and since it's a ListView, `GetLParam()` as [NMLVCUSTOMDRAW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-nmlvcustomdraw) if it is, verify `dwItemType = LVCDI_GROUP` and draw the text using your own Font and Color. -- Hard to maintain (and to handle all states).

Comment: @Jimi Damn, I have to use Win32 P/Invoke for this? And I have also found that I cannot add the sorting mark (like the Windows Explorer shows) without using P/Invoke. Why aren't Microsoft exposing those features to .NET when they themselves use them...

Comment: You can always use a WPF ListView - see the [VisualStyleElement.ListView.Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.listview.group) - and import the ListView in a UserControl with an ElementHost. -- Owner-drawing is quite normal in WinForms. You get used to it. In this case is somewhat more complex because you have different states and styles, also Dpi scale has a role, so it may take some time to get right, but it can be done, if it's worth the effort.